# How to restrict createObject() on certain java classes or packages?

Tags: coldfusion, jvm-arguments, java-security, cfadmin

I want to create a secure ColdFusion environment, for which I am using multiple sandboxes configuration. The following tasks are easily achievable using the friendly administrator interface:

- Restricting CFtags like: cfexecute, cfregistry and cfhttp.
- Disabling Access to Internal ColdFusion Java components.
- Access only to certain server and port ranges by third-party resources.

And the others using configuration of the web server accordingly.

### The Problem:

So I was satisfied with the setup only to encounter later that regardless of the restriction applied to the `cfexecute` tag one can use `java.lang.Runtime` to execute system files or scripts easily;

```
String[] cmd = {"cmd.exe", 'net stop "ColdFusion 10 Application Server"'};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

or using the `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", 'net stop "ColdFusion 10 Application Server"');
....
Process myProcess = pb.start();
```

The problem is that I cannot find any solutions which allows me to disable these two classes: `java.lang.Runtime` & `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` for the `createObject()`.
For the note: I have tried the file restriction in the sanbox and os permission as well, but unfortunately they seem to work on an I/O file operations only and I cannot mess with security policies of the system libraries as they might be used internally by ColdFusion.

Comment: Can you disable the `CreateObject(Java)` function via the GUI or will that be too restrictive?  What about the administrator setting under Settings `Disable access to internal ColdFusion Java components`? Did you check that.

Comment: Oops! Never mind, I see you already mentioned disabling access to the internal ColdFusion Java components in your question.

Comment: Disabling the `CreateObject(Java)` was my first thought in the after math, but then there is `CfObject` allowing the same functionality. And restricting both altogether would be indeed too much restrictive as they are used throughout the applications. If there is a way to disable only the `type=java` in both the cases, the issue will be solved. I am getting the feeling there might be some `JVM arguments` that might allow this restriction.

Comment: The `internal ColdFusion Java Components` does not cover java native libraries and just only the ColdFusion implementation of them, for instance: `Coldfusion.server.SystemInfo`, as per the short description given on the `server settings page` below the option, which says: "_Disables the ability for CFML code to access and create Java objects that are part of the internal ColdFusion implementation._"

Comment: I found a similar article. In it they are talking about security in a shared hosting environment but the issue mentioned is the same as you have found. Unfortunately they do not give a solution either. _So the hoster is left with a hard choice: disable CFEXECUTE, CFOBJECT, CreateObject(.NET), CreateObject(COM) and CreateObject(JAVA) or accept that there is no security whatsoever in the shared hosting configuration._ - http://jochem.vandieten.net/2008/12/09/cf-shared-hosting-security-java-cfexecute-com-net-and-java-again/

Comment: oh snap! This is so relevant scenario, but unfortunately no objective solution. Thanks for the resource @[Miguel-F](/users/1636917/miguel-f). I think I will start a bounty in 2 days.

Comment: It does make me wonder how hosting providers are dealing with this issue. It has been around long enough.

Comment: same here. I can't be more surprised with ColdFusion now. The hosting providers prefer multi-instance ColdFusion installation for better good, this might be one of the reasons why

Comment: From what I have read, you would normally implement some sort of a [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). (That *might* even be how CF implements the sandbox functionality).  However, I have no idea what impact, if any, a security policy would have on the rest of CF code.

Comment: Clear idea on how to proceed with it, But what are the `Security Manager` internals and how would it integrate with ColdFusion application. Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1007583/3098962) answer which suggest using a custom java classloader, which gives only a fair enough idea to run your thoughts around.

Comment: @[Leigh](/users/104223/leigh) I am going to go with the `Java Security Manager` approach. First step would be to handle permissions allowed for `java.lang.Runtime` using the `java.lang.RuntimePermission` object OR the second approach as I see a little clear now would be to modify `java.policy` file under `jre/lib/security` and remove permission mentioned there for the Runtime & ProcessBuilder classes. I too have no idea of the impact the security policy changes would have on the ColdFusion server itself and the application code. But I am going for trail and learn approach now. Thanks!

Comment: *modify java.policy file under jre/lib* @AnuragMishra - Yep, that is what I was thinking of (I do not see how a custom class loader would work in the context of a CF app).  Though again, no idea if it will negatively impact CF.  I would be curious to hear what you discover.

Comment: Just to clarify, yes ColdFusion uses the Security Manager when you enable the sandbox security. From the docs: _To use sandbox security in the J2EE editions, the application server must be running a security manager (java.lang.SecurityManager) and you define the following JVM arguments (for Tomcat, this is the java.args line in the cf_root/cfusion/bin/jvm.config file) - `-Djava.security.manager "-Djava.security.policy=cf_root/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/coldfusion.policy" "-Djava.security.auth.policy=cf_root/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/neo_jaas.policy"`_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the useful suggestions from @[Leigh](/users/104223/leigh) and @[Miguel-F](/users/1636917/miguel-f), I tried my hands on implementing the `Security Manager` and  `Policy`. Here's the outcome:

**1.** Specifying an Additional Policy File at runtime instead of making changes to the default `java.policy` file. To enable this, we add the following parameters to JVM arguments using CFAdmin interface or alternatively appending it to the `jvm.args` line in the `jvm.config` file :

> -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy="c:/policies/myRuntime.policy"

There is a nice GUI utility inside `jre\bin\` called `policytool.exe` which allows you to manage policy entries easily and efficiently.

**2.** We have enforced the Security manager and provided our custom security policy file which contains:

```
    grant codeBase "file:///D:/proj/secTestProj/main/-"{
        permission java.io.FilePermission 
        "<<ALL FILES>>", "read, write, delete";
    };
```

Here we are setting `FilePermission` for all files to `read, write, delete` excluding `execute` from the list as we do not want any type of file to be executed using the java runtime.

**Note:** The codebase can be set to an empty string if we want the policy to be applied to all the applications irrespective of the source.

I really wished for a `deny` rule in policy file to make things easier similar to the `grant` rule we're using, but there isn't unfortunately. If you need to put in place a set of complex security policies, you can use [Prograde](https://github.com/olukas/pro-grade) library, which implements policy file with deny rule ([stack ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21416571/3098962)).
You could surely replace `<<ALL FILES>>` with individual file and set permissions accordingly or for a better control use a combination of `<<ALL FILES>>` and individual file permissions.

References: [Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#Examples), [Permissions in JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html#RuntimePermission) and [Controlling Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour2/index.html)

This approach solves our core issue: denying execution of files using java runtime by specifying permissions allowed on a file. In other approach, we can implement `Security Manager` directly in our application to define policy file from there, instead of defining it in our JVM args.

```
//set the policy file as the system securuty policy
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:/C:/java.policy");
// create a security manager
SecurityManager sm = new SecurityManager();
//alternatively, get the current securiy manager using System.getSecuriyManager() 
//set the system security manager
System.setSecurityManager(sm);
```

To be able to set it, we need these permissions inside our policy file:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setSecurityManager";
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createSecurityManager";
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "usePolicy";
```

Using [Security Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) object inside an application has its own advantages as it exposes many useful methods For instance: `CheckExec(String cmd)` which checks whether a calling thread is allowed to create a sub-process or not.

```
//perform the check
try{
  sm.checkExec("notepad.exe");
}
catch(SecurityException e){
  //do something...show warning.
}
```

Comment: Great information. Thanks for posting it. I look forward to trying it out :)

Comment: I still think there must a better way to achieve what we intend here, using the `Security Manager` and Policy files. I got around to using the  `java.io.FilePermission` as there wasn't any target name available in [java.lang.RuntimePermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html#RuntimePermission) to achieve such objective (which I initially expected to be found here). Another elegant solution would be to use custom _`ClassLoaders`_ to filter out the two classes we were initially concerned about: `java.lang.Runtime` & `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: The problem I saw with using a custom ClassLoaders was I am not so sure you could work into the normal application flow as simply as with a policy file. That said, I have not done any experimentation with it, so I could be totally off base ...

Comment: I agree, even if custom class loaders were a solution, they won't fit so normally as the policy mechanism and for that I too don't have any experience, another reason to keep this question open. A [good read](http://www.securingjava.com/chapter-three/chapter-three-7.html) on java security, I found just recently. And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/502388/3098962) answer on sandboxing in java application and [Access Controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html) made me think there must be an alternate solution, if arguably not better and clean one.

Comment: I wish someone could post a solution using custom class loaders. As I learn more and about it, I see the scope for the custom class loaders to be a good alternate solution as well. I still don't posses proper advanced java knowledge to go about that solution, but working on it.

Comment: I do not see how you could implement it for a CF application - not cleanly/consistently/securely. The CF server already implements its own AccessControllers, and custom class loaders, as part of createObject. So you would have to hook into them somehow/override them without running afoul of CF's internal logic. Far from a trivial task. Also, given the complexity of the security specs, there is the potential to make things MUCH worse if you do not know what you are doing ;-) I would never apply it on a live system, but it would be interesting to experment with on a DEV box.

Comment: *hook into them somehow/override them without running afoul of CF's internal logic* ... in such a way that it was always enforced for all createObject calls. Not sure that is possible without a brittle/ugly hack.

Comment: I am going to mark the only answer as accepted, I wish the bounty points could be claimed before grace period.

Comment: Though I would be happy to be proven wrong, I really think the custom class loader approach is not a feasible one for a *CF* application. There is just no clean way to enforce it that I can see ...

Comment: I agree to that now. I tried my chances with it but only found complications but I attribute it to my lack of knowledge both the environments. Anyways, I am happy as I was able to get my hands on security management in ColdFusion and experiment with it to expand my knowledge base. I will get back to my answer to expand it in future. Thanks for all the guidance!